# How to fetch the latest post through twitter api

Tags: twitter

I want to fetch only the post and display it as my requirement? How to do it using twitter api.? Any help is accepted.Please provide code the documentation is not upto mark.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I tried OAUTH or something i got the code from some source.But it is not working.I have the tokens and all.

Comment: What do you mean by "latest post"? You post? Someone else's?

Comment: I want client's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline):

To retrieve a user's posts, you need to make a call to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

If you only want the latest post, you need to add `count=1`

So, to get the latest post from *my* account, use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=edent&count=1
```

You will need to sign the request with OAuth.